# Zend Framework: How to edit the Error Controller to handle login required/auauthorized access errors?

Tags: zend-framework

i am creating a acl controller plugin that checks the if the user is authorized to the resource and redirect to the error controller to handle it. how do i go abt doing this?

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html
Look at Error Controllers. You need to create a ErrorController class and an action with the default name -> errorAction. Then check permission in your ACL plugin and if denied forward to this controller. Theres several ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this question on SO: [Help with Zend ACL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545702/help-with-zend-acl).
Another good ACL/Auth tutorial can by found at devzone: [Zend_Acl / Zend_Auth Example Scenario](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1665) (The codelisting is incomplete but have a look at the comment "THE MISSING PIECES")

The important part is in the preDispatch Plugin:

```
$controller = $request->controller;
$action     = $request->action;
$module     = $request->module;
$resource   = $controller;

if (!$this->_acl->isAllowed($role, $resource, $action)) {
    if (!$this->_auth->hasIdentity()) {
        $module     = 'default';
        $controller = 'login';
        $action     = 'index';
    } else {
        $module     = 'default';
        $controller = 'error';
        $action     = 'privileges';
    }
}

$request->setModuleName($module);
$request->setControllerName($controller);
$request->setActionName($action);
```

If the is not logged in or has insufficient rights the request will be modified to forward to the Loginpage or the error controller.

Comment: this is a great answer for my other question :) to redirect from controller plugins. use `Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Redirector')`. here, i am wondering how i can edit the error controller to show error messages to the user eg. if they are trying to access an unauthorized resource