# The best way to manage zend roles for various user roles

Tags: zend-framework, acl, authentication

I have resources to which I want to bind visibility for many roles of user. How can I bind the Zend_Auth with the Zend_ACL and get resources from the database.

Answer (score 1):

There are more than plenty of ways to accomplish what your doing... Presuming you already have an ACL class created in your library and another class that does the actual verifying, I like to store the actual roles/resources in a config file and just load it in during bootstrap, then using the ACL class to iterate through and create the roles and resources.

Like I said there's plenty of places to find this, one would be here on SO [Need guidance to start with Zend ACL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545702/help-with-zend-acl)

I would also suggest, that with any site you find info or a tutorial on - start with the actual documentation first: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.multiuser.html

The learning curve is the hardest boundary with it, but once your past it gets simpler.

I hope that helps even slightly.